# Entity framework insert fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-extensions

Using EF6 + EF extensions for bulk deletion.

In the code I'm doing 2 things: First, clean all related entities, and second add new related entities. Just to avoid checking for similarity.

This main objects class:

```
[Table("distrule")]
public class Distrule: CommonEntity
{
    //other properties
    public virtual ICollection<Distrule_content> DistruleContent { get; set; }
}

[Table("distrule_content")]
public class Distrule_content
{
    [Key,Column(Order=0)]
    public int distrule_id { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string IDEC { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("distrule_id")]
    public virtual Distrule Distrule { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IDEC")]
    public virtual Content Content { get; set; }
}
```

Here is deletion-1 code:

```
Db.Distrule_contents.Where(x=> x.distrule_id == DistruleId).Delete();
Db.SaveChanges();
```

This is deletion-2 code:

```
List<Distrule_content> dcs = Distrule.DistruleContent.ToList();
dcs.Select(x => { Db.Entry(x).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted; return x; }).ToList();
Db.SaveChanges();
```

And after some manipulations add new entries:

```
//dc has type of List<Distrule_content> and contain new collection.
Db.Distrule_contents.AddRange(dc);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

So when I use deletion-1 to make it faster (in some cases there are up to 10K entries to delete) I got this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The changes to the database were
>   committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the
>   object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state.
>   Inner exception message: Saving or accepting changes failed because
>   more than one entity of type 'IDS.DAL.Entities.Distrule_content' have
>   the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key
>   values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are
>   configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework
>   model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First
>   configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or
>   'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute'

When I use deletion-2 everything is OK, just longer.

All operations with db context works in transaction scope like this:

```
new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout });
```

Db context looks like this:

```
public class DBWrapper : DbContext
{
    public DBWrapper()
        : base("Name=DefaultConnection")
    {

        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)this;
        var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
        objectContext.CommandTimeout = 30; // value in seconds
        // set this for faster delete/insert operations
        // reduce wait time from minute or two to 10-15 seconds
        this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }
    // dbsets...
}
```

how to avoid this exception, since I want to use this extension for EF?

Comment: There are multiple problems here: 1) in both cases you don't delete - you load a *lot* of objects, mark some (all in q2) for deletion then cause EF to issue a *lot* of single delete statements. If you want to do batch manipulations, execute a SQL statement or write a stored procedure to do it. Such a delete should take less than half a second. 2) You have a composite key but in the first query you only delete entities that match *one* of the columns. When you add the new data, you obviously enter key values that are already present in the database.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Both q1 and q2 do same thing, delete related entities specified by distrule_id, in first case id specified, in second case object specified. 
1. Already tried execute SQL statement like `delete from Distrule_contents where distrule_id = {0}` with specified ID. Same exception. Put all busines logic to stored procedure isn't the best solution for this stage of project completion.
2. Event with composite key, deletion by distrule_id should delete all entries, and inserting new shouldn't conflict.

Comment: 1) Which means that *still* trying to write entities with existing keys. The problem isn't the query, it's that you add values that already exist in the database. The new entries need to have a unique `IDEC` and `distrule_id` combination, but you are trying to add existing combinations. 2) Data manipulation statements aren't business logic. You are trying to delete all entries with a specific value, not execute some business function. 3) Your context is probably missing existing `IDEC` entries that you are trying to insert. As a result, your code never realizes it's trying to insert duplicates

Comment: The two queries do *very different* things. `Q1` deletes loaded entities that contain a specific `distrule_id`. `Q2` marks for deletion **all loaded entities**, which can only work if you loaded the entries you wanted to delete in the first place. Both queries result in `N` delete statements where only 1 statements is needed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok. Got it. Anyway there are lot things to do. As variant replace current logic to choose which entry to delete and which to insert.

Answer (score 0):

The `Delete` method is an immediate operation.

When you call it, you don't need to call after `SaveChanges` and therefore, you will not get this error.

---

It's currently unclear which library you are using (You are saying "EF extensions for bulk deletion." in the question but have tagged initially "entity-framework-extended".

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of all those products.

[EF Extended](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.Extended) is no longer supported since 2014,

It is recommended to move to:

- [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/) (Free and Open Source)
- [Entity Framework Extensions](https://entityframework-extensions.net/) (Commercial but the `Delete` from query feature is free)

Both of those products also have this feature.